# C# Compact Code on Cameras, Is it possible?

Tags: c#

I have one peices of code that should be repeated 5 times as follows:

```
VideoCaptureDevice videoSource3 = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[2].MonikerString);
videoSource3.DesiredFrameRate = 10;
videoSourcePlayer3.VideoSource = videoSource3; 
videoSourcePlayer3.Start();
```

All of index 3 should vary between 1 to 5.

Is there any compact form instead of coding this 4lines 5 times?

Comment: Have you considered using an array or a list?

Comment: Yes, very short, but couldn't progress very well.@MikeNakis

Comment: If you are trying to increase speed than using a static object would allow you to initialize only once and then change one value each time.  You would need to make sure that the object is not used simultaneously by more than one process.  If you did use with multiprocessing than you would need to add a lock around code to prevent conflicts.

Comment: @jdweng: I don't believe the OP is concerned with efficiency, but just about reducing code duplication.

Comment: @DaisyShipton Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that it's almost always better to have a collection than to have multiple variables declared with indexes after their names. That way you can operate on them all in a uniform way. That doesn't always play nicely with UI frameworks which often like to have a single variable per control, admittedly - but there's often a way round that if you're looking for it.

You haven't shown the `videoSourcePlayer3` initialization, but I'm going to assume for now that you want to create all the players, based on the devices (which are already in a collection, by the looks of it).

You can start doing that easily enough with just lists and loops. I've had to guess at some of the names.

```
// Create the players
List<VideoPlayer> videoSourcePlayers = new List<VideoPlayer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    VideoCaptureDevice source = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[i].MonikerString);
    source.DesiredFrameRate = 10;
    VideoPlayer player = new VideoPlayer();
    player.VideoSource = source;
    videoSourcePlayers.Add(player);
}

// Start all the players
foreach (VideoPlayer player in videoSourcePlayers)
{
    player.Start();
}
```

Next up, using *object initializers* to make the code in the first loop simpler. (I won't show the code in the second loop again - it would be the same for each snippet.)

```
List<VideoPlayer> videoSourcePlayers = new List<VideoPlayer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    videoSourcePlayers.Add(new VideoPlayer
    {
        VideoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[i].MonikerString)
            { DesiredFrameRate = 10 }
    });
}
```

Next, notice that this is really just a transformation of `videoDevices` - so we can use LINQ to simplify it:

```
List<VideoPlayer> videoSourcePlayers = videoDevices
    .Select(device => new VideoCaptureDevice(device.MonikerString) { DesiredFrameRate = 10 })
    .Select(source => new VideoPlayer { VideoSource = source })
    .ToList();
```

(You could do it with a single select, but I think it's clearer with two in this particular case.)